# ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 1225] The remote computer refused the network connection

Tags: python, runtime-error, python-asyncio, oserror

I'm running this code in VS Code:

```
import asyncio

async def tcp_echo_client(message):
    reader, writer = await asyncio.open_connection(
        '127.0.0.1', 80)

    print(f'Send: {message!r}')
    writer.write(message.encode())
    await writer.drain()

    data = await reader.read(100)
    print(f'Received: {data.decode()!r}')

    print('Close the connection')
    writer.close()
    await writer.wait_closed()

asyncio.run(tcp_echo_client('Hello World!'))
```

It's exactly the same in Python's original docs, but I have no idea why I get that error.

In Spyder the error's a little different:
`RuntimeError: asyncio.run() cannot be called from a running event loop`

I also tried different IPs and ports.
When I tried another IP like Google's DNS, (8.8.8.8), I encountered this another weird error:
`OSError: [WinError 121] The semaphore timeout period has expired`

Comment: Nothing was listening at the IP:port you tried to connect to.